# Is there a way to convert an SQL Server's script to Oracle's script

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I want to run this SQL script into oracle. I have tried to use a MSSQL script converter. And this was the results but does not work.

```
Update c
SET `c.SOURCE BLOCK LEVEL` = CONCAT('B',SUBSTR(g.HIERARCHY, GREATEST(-LENGTH(g.HIERARCHY),-LENGTH(RTRIM(g.HIERARCHY)) - 12)))
FROM mshist>dbo<CYCLE AS c
INNER JOIN `msmodel.dbo.GRADEBLOCK` AS g
ON `c.SOURCE BLOCK` IS NOT NULL AND
`c.SOURCE BLOCK LEVEL` IS NULL AND 
g.HIERARCHY LIKE 'root:Blocks:%' AND
`c.SOURCE BLOCK` = g.GRADEBLOCK_OID;


UPDATE C
SET `c.SOURCE BLOCK LEVEL` = CONCAT('S',SUBSTR(g.HIERARCHY, GREATEST(-LENGTH(g.HIERARCHY),-LENGTH(RTRIM(g.HIERARCHY)) - 16)))
FROM mshist.dbo AS c
INNER JOIN msmodel.dbo.GRADEBLOCK AS g
ON `c.SOURCE BLOCK` IS NOT NULL AND
`c.SOURCE BLOCK LEVEL` IS NULL AND
g.HIERARCHY LIKE 'root:Stockpiles:%' AND
`c.SOURCE BLOCK` = g.GRADEBLOCK_OID;
```

Comment: did you use it service http://www.sqlines.com/online

Comment: `SQL` is the name for standard database language and not a property of MSSQL to be used in a generic way. You should say "I want to convert a T-SQL code to Oracle " or  "SQL-Server script to Oracle".

Comment: That syntax is invalid for Microsoft SQL Server. Looks more like MySQL due to those dreaded backticks (which are used incorrectly to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

Right; code you got won't work in Oracle, but something like this might:

```
update cycle c set
  c.source block level = 
   (select concat('B', substr(g.hierarchy, 
                              greatest(-length(g.hierarchy), -length(rtrim(g.hierarchy)) - 12)
                             )
                 )
    from gradeblock g
    where c.source block = g.gradeblock_oid
      and g.hierarchy like 'root:Blocks:%'
   )
where c.source block is not null
  and c.source block level is null;
```

- you might need to adjust table names (in `UPDATE` and `FROM`)
- substring's starting position looks suspicious; it seems that it is a *negative* number. Is it? If so, it isn't an error - it just means that will be counting backwards from the end of the `g.hierarchy` string

See if it helps.

Comment: thank all for your comments , i was ultimately able to convert the scripts to work with oracle